# How to fill a dataframe with times in between two times that are in the dataframe?

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to fill my data frame with dates and times that are in between a "Start_dates" and "End_dates", which are both in different columns in the data frame. I would like to do this per minute.

So for example I have a data frame like this:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,3),
                   Start_dates = c("20-10-2016 00:00:00", "23-10-2016 00:00:00", "01-03-2018 00:00:00", "05-12-2018 00:00:00", "02-04-2016 00:00:00"),
                   End_dates = c("20-10-2016 00:02:00", "23-10-2016 00:01:00", "01-03-2018 00:01:00", "05-12-2018 00:02:00", "02-04-2016 00:01:00"))
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
     data_requested <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
      times = c("20-10-2016 00:00:00",
      "20-10-2016 00:01:00", "20-10-2016 00:02:00", "23-10-2016 00:00:00",
     "23-10-2016 00:01:00", "01-03-2018 00:00:00", "01-03-2018 00:01:00", 
     "05-12-2018 00:00:00", "05-12-2018 00:01:00", "05-12-2018 00:02:00", 
     "02-04-2016 00:00:00", "02-04-2016 00:01:00"))
```

I tried a lot of things but it gave me either an error or not the result that I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We convert the 'Start_dates/End_dates' to datetime, and use `map2` to get the sequence

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
    # convert dates to DateTime object
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('dates')), dmy_hms) %>%
    # get the sequence between corresponding Start/End dates 
    mutate(times =  map2(Start_dates, End_dates, seq, by = "1 min")) %>%
    # unnest to expand the list column
    unnest(times) %>% 
    # select the wanted columns
    select(id, times)
#   id               times
#1   1 2016-10-20 00:00:00
#2   1 2016-10-20 00:01:00
#3   1 2016-10-20 00:02:00
#4   1 2016-10-23 00:00:00
#5   1 2016-10-23 00:01:00
#6   1 2018-03-01 00:00:00
#7   1 2018-03-01 00:01:00
#8   2 2018-12-05 00:00:00
#9   2 2018-12-05 00:01:00
#10  2 2018-12-05 00:02:00
#11  3 2016-04-02 00:00:00
#12  3 2016-04-02 00:01:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!